# PHP associative array of other arrays, how to delete/search elements?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have this array

```
$myarr = Array (
    [0] => Array1 ( [6] => 1 )
    [1] => Array1 ( [1] => 1 )
    [2] => Array1 ( [1] => 4 )
)
```

I want to delete an element 'Array1' where key is '1' and value associated to that key is '4'.

Comment: you can use unset ``unset($myarr[0][5]);``

Comment: `Array1` is **not** a thing.

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.array.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `array_map`

```
function filter($value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $key=>$val) {
            if(!($key==1 && $val==4)){
                return $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
$myarr = [[6=>1],[1=>1],[1=>4]];
$myarr = array_filter(array_map("filter", $myarr));
```

or `array_filter`

```
$myarr = [[6=>1],[1=>1],[1=>4]];
print_r($myarr);
$newarr = [];
foreach($myarr as $arr){
    $newarr[] = array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
        return !($k == 1 && $v == 4);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);  
}
$myarr = array_filter($newarr);
```

You can check both examples in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99a171fe54ad759e640232737517c0797120f07e)